# Replace first occurrence in class

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="section truck edit-track truck-army truck-ambulance"></div>
```

How do I replace only first `truck` to `truck garage-active`?

We should get this:

```
<div class="section truck garage-active edit-track truck-army truck-ambulance"></div>
```

Not this:

```
<div class="section truck edit-track truck-army truck-ambulance garage-active"></div>
```

jQuery `.addClass()` just adds a new class to the end of the class name, so it doesn't help - http://jsfiddle.net/xxbnt/

Need this for the right **CSS class chaining** styles.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with `addClass`, because it would produce the equivalent of the shown output.

Comment: -1: "it doesn't help at all" - this is patently false. Verify that a problem even exists before posting to SO.

Comment: @WaleedKhan **Are you sure?** http://jsfiddle.net/xxbnt/

Comment: @Steve Hence “the equivalent”.

Comment: Why does the order of the classes matter?

Comment: Hey, I've updated a question. They are not equal due to CSS class chaining.

Comment: CSS doesn't care what order the classes are listed in. `.class1.class2` is equivalent to `.class2.class1`.

Comment: @Steve What you have here is not css chaining. The only thing that matters is the order you have your class defined in the stylesheet.

Comment: @Steve Share more code so that we can get what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="truck garage-active edit-track truck-army truck-ambulance"></div>
```

is the same as

```
<div class="truck edit-track truck-army truck-ambulance garage-active"></div>
```

The order of class names doesn't matter.

Your code is perfectly fine with `addClass()`.

**Update**

As [Blazemonger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901048/blazemonger) pointed out, the order only matters if you do something like

```
$(".truck")[0].className.split(' ')[1]
```

which will require the `garage-active` to be just after `truck`. In all other cases, you have no problems.

Comment: split won't work with updated question

Comment: @Steve I was just pointing out the scenario you are having, using `split` won't solve your problem. :)